# elements could not be linked, which elements to link?(gstreamer c)

Tags: c, gstreamer

I've been studying about gstreamer and I don't understand where I got it wrong but every pipeline I tried turning code would give me 'Elements could not be linked' and I'm running this code on ubuntu 20.04 which has an upstream kernel version 5.13.0-35(which I think is not a concern) with gcc 9 and here is the code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it to callbacks */
typedef struct _CustomData {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *source;
  GstCaps *caps;
  GstElement *depay;
  GstElement *parse;
  GstElement *decode;
  GstElement *convert;
  GstElement *sink;
} CustomData;


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CustomData data;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  data.source = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsrc", "source");
  data.caps = gst_caps_new_simple("application/x-rtp", 
    "media", G_TYPE_STRING, "video",
    "clock-rate", G_TYPE_INT, 90000,
    "encoding-name", G_TYPE_STRING, "H264",
    "payload", G_TYPE_INT, 96,
    NULL);
  data.depay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264depay", "depay");
  data.parse = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "parse");
  data.decode = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin", "decode");
  data.convert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "convert");
  data.sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!data.pipeline || !data.source || !data.depay || !data.parse || !data.decode  || !data.convert || !data.sink) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source, data.depay, data.parse, data.decode, data.convert, data.sink, NULL);
  if (gst_element_link_many (data.source, data.depay, data.parse, data.decode, data.convert, data.sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
  }  
  /* Set the port and caps to play */
  g_object_set (data.source, "port", 5000, NULL);
  g_object_set (data.source, "caps", data.caps, NULL);
  g_object_set (data.sink, "sync", FALSE, NULL);


  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
            GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n",
            debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error (&err);
        g_free (debug_info);
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
        break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

the recieving pipeline is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

And the sender is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=$HOST port=5000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot directly link decodebin. You need to connect a pad-added signal and link in the callback at runtime.

Comment: thanks, could you link an example?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using gst_parse_launch() that will negociate caps as gst-launch does:

```
const gchar *pipeline_str = "udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false";
GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch (pipeline_str, NULL);
if (!pipeline) {
   g_error ("Failed to create pipeline\n");
   exit(-1);
}
...
```

Otherwise, you may have to add capsfilters.

Comment: sorry, couldn't solve the problem this way, could explain a bit more about capsfilters? you think the problem happens when I do g_object_set for caps? thanks btw

Comment: You may tell more about what doesn't work. If it fails to run, you may post the code you're trying and the error logs. If your concern is about getting control into plugins properties, you would just give each a `name=myplugin_given_name` in the pipeline and you would be able to get pointer to each element with `GstElement *myplugin = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "myplugin_given_name");`.

Comment: I alredy posted the code and the problem is that the elements can't be linked, as marmikshah suggests in the question's comment, the error is produced because decodebin can't be linked this way, and you said that it may be about capsfilters so I just wanted to know what you think about the error, thanks.

Comment: I proposed to use gst_launch_parse instead of building the pipeline by hand. This would imply many changes in your code. Google for it for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: My last comment was not correct. Sorry I typed it quickly and realized too late for editing. Search for `gst_parse_launch` instead.

Comment: that's alright, thanks